# Adding an element to two elements in a list at a time

Tags: python, list, append

Not too sure how to build this, but I am trying to add one element from one list to another.

```
x = [1,1,2,2,3,3]

a=[['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['g'],['h'],['i'],['j'],['k'],['l'],['m']]
```

And I'm trying to get an output like this where it adds one element:

```
a=[['b',1],['c',1],['d',2],['e',2],['f',3],['g',3],['h',1],['i',1],['j',2],['k',2],['l',3],['m',3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **modify** the lists, you can use a `for` loop and use `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

for ai,xi in zip(a,cycle(x)):
    ai.append(xi)
```

which gives:

```
>>> a
[['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f', 3], ['g', 3], ['h', 1], ['i', 1], ['j', 2], ['k', 2], ['l', 3], ['m', 3]]
```

If you do not care about the original lists, you can also use *list comprehension* to construct a **new list of lists**:

```
a[:] = [ai+[xi] for ai,xi in zip(a,cycle(x))]
```

which gives:

```
>>> [ai+[xi] for ai,xi in zip(a,cycle(x))]
[['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['d', 2], ['e', 2], ['f', 3], ['g', 3], ['h', 1], ['i', 1], ['j', 2], ['k', 2], ['l', 3], ['m', 3]]
```

Comment: If you want to modify the list, perhaps re-assign the list comp with a slice like `a[:] = `

Comment: @Chris_Rands: that's a good idea, but the individual lists will still not update: so if for instance you had a variable `sublist = a[0]`, that variable will not modify. That's not *per se* a problem. But it is something to take into account.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished in native Python by using the mod operator:

```
x = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
a=[['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['g'],['h'],['i'],['j'],['k'],['l'],['m']]
results = [[value[0], x[index % len(x)]] for index, value in enumerate(a)]
print(results)
```